# In NHibernate, my check if entity is dirty fails

Tags: nhibernate

### Background

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541864/can-i-tell-if-a-property-is-dirty-using-nhibernate), I need to determine if an entity in my NHibernate application is dirty or not.  There is a "IsDirty" method on ISession, but I want to check a specific entity, not the whole session.

[This post on nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/finding-dirty-properties-in-nhibernate) describes a method of checking an entity by fetching its database state and comparing it to the current state of the entity.

### Problem

I've copied that method, but it isn't working for me.  See the code:

```
public static Boolean IsDirtyEntity(this ISession session, Object entity)
{
    String className = NHibernateProxyHelper.GuessClass(entity).FullName;
    ISessionImplementor sessionImpl = session.GetSessionImplementation();
    IPersistenceContext persistenceContext = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext;
    IEntityPersister persister = sessionImpl.Factory.GetEntityPersister(className);
    EntityEntry oldEntry = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(entity);


    if ((oldEntry == null) && (entity is INHibernateProxy))
    {
        INHibernateProxy proxy = entity as INHibernateProxy;
        Object obj = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext.Unproxy(proxy);
        oldEntry = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(obj);
    }

    Object [] oldState = oldEntry.LoadedState;
    Object [] currentState = persister.GetPropertyValues(entity, sessionImpl.EntityMode);
    Int32 [] dirtyProps = persister.FindDirty(currentState, oldState, entity, sessionImpl);

    return (dirtyProps != null);
}
```

The line that that populates the currentState array by calling persister.GetPropertyValues() is the problem.  The array is full of nulls, instead of the actual values from my entity.

When I stepped into the code, I found that reflection is being used to get the values from the fields -- but the fields are null.  This seems like a result of the proxy, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed my default-access strategy from "field.camelcase-underscore" to "property" and now the `persister.GetPropertyValues()` method returns correct values.

Too early to declare victory, but seems interesting.  I was using the field access strategy because I had code in my entities' properties to track dirty state.  Since I'm removing that code and going to rely on NH to determine dirty state, I was able to use the property access strategy.