# Is there a way to know if an entity has been managed by NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have bunch of entities and I would like to know which one has been Save() with NHibernate (no flush yet). How can I do it ?

Comment: *Fluent* NHibernate, specifically, or just NHibernate? That is, are you trying to differentiate entities by whether they were mapped via FNH or HBM?

Comment: No, I am wondering to know if an entities has been called Save() on him.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This hasn't anything to do then with Fluent. Do you have access also to the `ISession` on which `Save()` was called, or only to the entities?

Comment: this has already been answered here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541864/can-i-tell-if-a-property-is-dirty-using-nhibernate

Comment: Yes, I have access to the ISession.  I will try the Oenning's answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Hibernate's Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/), the Session has a method called `Contains(obj)`.

> ```
> boolean contains(Object object)
>     Check if this instance is associated with this Session.
>
> Parameters:
>     object - an instance of a persistent class
>
> Returns:
>     true if the given instance is associated with this Session
> ```

Well, I suppose this should work in your case since your newly created object does not get in touch with the ISession before you call `Save` (or `Get`). Give it a try and tell us what happens.

Another option would be creating an abstraction on top of the ISession and implement your own code to check if the entity has already been saved or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering if something has been persisted by NHibernate you could probably just check the 'ID' field and see if it has changed from the default value

Comment: The presence of an ID does not guarantee that the entity has been persisted. Identity/Native is only one of many identity-generating algorithms supported by NHibernate. Others, such as HiLo (used to reduce queries against the database and improve performance), assign identifiers before (but not necessarily immediately before) inserting records to the database.